# WPF validation WITHOUT object in datacontext

Tags: wpf

This one is driving me crazy:-)

Lets say I have some test xaml code:

```
    <Window x:Class="ProWPFInCSharpyTestProject.ValidationTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ValidationTest" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Margin="10" Name="someTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Name="SomeTextBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" Name="errorMessageTextBlock"  />
        <Button Content="Click Me" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, I have **no object** bound to it, because it will collect data from the form and throw it in the database. But now I want to validate if the fields are empty when the button is clicked and show an error message. Almost every single tutorial I have looked at has an object bound to the grid but this is not relevant to me.

Why can't this be more like asp.net? Just put a validator with a validator group. It would things so much less cryptic and complex than it is now.

Comment: actually having an object in `DataContext` will make it much easier, hundred times easier than it was in Asp.Net, but you have to master `MVVM` for that.

Comment: Yeah, I have been looking at MVVM, but talk about cryptic :-). Anyways, the thing is that I don't have or want an object in my DataContext. I just want to check if multiple textboxes are empty and show a error. That's it.

Comment: True, I need to name them :-) I was thinking more along the line of validators like asp.net. Validator(s) check if textbox is empty, collect them from the controls you have on your form when pressing button et voila.

Comment: Using the form to collect input and write it doesn't mean you can't use a `DataContext`. In any case, for validation you need to use `Binding` (unless you want to do it all by yourself). You have to bind either to properties in the `DataContext` or, if you have none, to properties defined straight on the `Window` subclass.

Comment: The form I really need to program it into is a form for adding a new MemberShipUser - The fields are UserName, PassWord, Email - but as well all the roles they have. Colleagues have extended MemberShipUser with the class Member that holds a list of Roles. All of the code is written with code behind code. It's messy and I can't just write stuff....

Comment: But what I don't get is this - When I have to make for example a new user, would I add an empty user object to the datacontext of my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry man, but you're doing WPF not ASP.NET. I understand that WPF can be frustrating but is not a good idea to bend a technology to your old habits.
Having said that, You're talking about gathering the data entered then pass it to the database.
One way to do it in WPF is using a ViewModel or any object to act as some kind of container. The WPF binding stuff will tell you if something went wrong. Then you can pass/translate your objects to the Data Layer/ORM and then lastly hit the database.

Maybe Kent approach works, but not in complex scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

OK, assuming you *really* don't want a model:

```
    <TextBox Margin="10" Name="someTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Name="SomeTextBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" Name="errorMessageTextBlock"  />
    <Button Name="button" Content="Click Me" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Then in the code behind:

```
button.Click += delegate
{
    if (someTextBox.Text == "" && someTextBox2.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error!");
    }
    else
    {
        DoSomethingCool();
    }
};
```

As a hacky way to use the validation infrastructure without defining your own model, you could do this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <!-- whatever rules you want here -->
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This hijacks the `TextBox.Tag` property as a place to store the bound data, which enables you to use `Binding.ValidationRules`.

**But you're really resisting one of WPF's strongest attractions by not using data binding.**

The clean way to do this is to define a model, bind the view to that model, and implement `IDataErrorInfo` in your model if you want validation.

Comment: Using WPF in that way is like giving a grenade to a monkey. Even though he asked for it.